# How can I create datareport using recordset in vb6?

Tags: oracle, vb6, rdbms

```
Private Sub showreport_Click()
    sql = "select * from student_record_database where"
    sql=sql+ Grade='" & Combo1.Text & "' AND Meal='" & Combo11.Text & "'"
    Set RES = CON.Execute(sql)
    Set DataReport1.DataSource = RES
    DataReport1.WindowState = vbMaximized
    DataReport1.Show vbModal
End Sub
```

I am using this code as record set to create a data report.

1. My task is to choose options from various combo boxes and then display it's report so record set is needed there..
2. My question is that whether this code is sufficient to create data report???
3. I didn't set any properties of data environment or data report such as      (connection - command - sql) because I am passing this record set directly to data report,then no need to fire any sql in properties of data environment.

But unfortunately it is not showing desired output
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Private sub cmdprint_click()

Dim rs as new adodb.recordset

rs.open "SQL Query Statement Here",CON, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic

set datareport1.datasource=rs
datareport1.show

end sub
```

**Notes:**
The data report datasouce should be cleared during design mode. (See properties on the datareport and set its datasource property to empty.) Ohhh...one more thing, please keep in mind that you should set also the datafield property for each textbox object inside the datareport corresponding to the datafield on your database during design time...

I am using this method for a long time and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
To add a quite to a string, use a double quite.
Also you missed spelled the second Combo1 reference as Combo11

```
Private Sub showreport_Click()
  sql = "select * from student_record_database where "
  sql = sql & "Grade=""" & Combo1.Text & """ AND Meal=""" & Combo1.Text & """"
  Set RES = CON.Execute(sql)
  Set DataReport1.DataSource = RES
  DataReport1.WindowState = vbMaximized
  DataReport1.Show vbModal
End Sub
```

Comment: No sir,it is another combo i.e.combo 11 showing meal facility of student and combo 1 shows standard of student,I want to filter these 2 fields and then show the report ..................................................................... problem is that it works when I gives data source using data environment - connection - command - sql etc......................... but when I am passing record set to data report it shows empty data report.............

Comment: I think I see why now.  Are you using a data control for your DB connection.  Your passing your dataset to the form and not a data control.

Comment: Sir,I don't understand what you are trying to say...... please clear my doubts,I am using ADODB and RES is record set of it.........

Comment: Set DataReport1.DataSource = RES
Your passing the results to your form, not your ADODB control.
Set DataReport1.ADODBControl.DataSource = RES